# Use findstr to Search a Sub Directory for a String?

Tags: cmd.exe, string, findstr

I can use the following to search for text files that contain the word "string" from the Windows Command Prompt:

```
C:\>findstr /spin /c:"string" *.txt
```

What if I want to search a sub-directory? The following doesn't work:

```
C:\>findstr /spin /c:\Users\My Name\Desktop"string" *.txt
```

Is it possible to search a specific sub path using findstr? I know I can do the following, but I'm trying to avoid having to change directories first:

```
C:\Users\My Name\Desktop>C:\>findstr /spin /c:"string" *.txt
```

Comment: `findstr /spin /c:"string" "c:\Users\My Name\Desktop\*.txt"`

Comment: If you post this as an answer I'll accept it as it's just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question appears to me quite bit vaguely formulated. 
Read [program documentation](http://ss64.com/nt/) in any doubt (`findstr /?` or http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html in this case).

```
findstr /spin /c:"string" "c:\Users\My Name\Desktop\*.txt"
```